# What is hom-set of small ordinal numbers?

Tags: category-theory, ordinals

I'm reading Mac Lane's category theory book. There's an example on page 123 which assumes **Ord** to be the ordered set of all small ordinal numbers *a*, *b*, ... . It would be a category with hom-set **Ord**(*a* , *b*) empty or the one-point set according as *a* *>* *b* or *a* <= *b*.

Can you please explain it?

Comment: If you want your questions to be answered quickly, write down the entire example, relevant details and format using mathjax. That way people won't have to go through the trouble of downloading the pdf and finding the example.

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Comment: Imagine writing down the ordered set of all ordinals. Then replace all $\leq$ signs by an arrow. The graph you get then is a depiction of the category Mac Lane describes.

Comment: Thank you @S.Farr for your comment. I got it. I also appreciate if you have suggestions on editting the question so that it can possibly help someone else.